# How to add spaces in between rows of text that are not the same

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for a way to add spaces in between rows. The only time I want it to add a space is when the text is not the same as the row above it. I am having some trouble and can't quite figure it out. Here is what I have got so far:

```
Sub Spaces()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim Text1 As String
    Dim Text2 As String
        For Each cell In Selection
    Text1 = Cells(cell, 1).Text
    Text2 = Cells(cell - 1, 1).Text
    If InStr(1, cell, "-", 1) Then
        If Cells(cell, 1) <> Cells(cell - 1, 1) Then
        Else: Cells(cell + 1, 1).EntireRow.Insert
        End If
    End If
    Next    
End Sub
```

Any clues as to where I am going wrong would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I used to separate rows that held different tubing sizes.

```
Sub blastListSort()

Range("A1").Resize(Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row, _
      Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Column).Select


For rown = Selection.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1

Size = Cells(rown, 3).Value
Size2 = Cells(rown, 3).Offset(-1).Value
lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If Size2 <> Size Then
Cells(rown, 6).EntireRow.Select
Cells(rown, 6).EntireRow.Insert
End If


Next
End Sub
```

Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Without changing it too much, you could try something like this:

```
Sub Spaces()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim Text1 As String
    Dim Text2 As String
    For Each cell In Selection

        ' initialize first string
        Text1 = cell.Text

        ' initialize second string for first time through
        If Text2 = vbNullString Then Text2 = Text1

        ' perform test
        If InStr(1, Text1, "-", 1) Then
            If Text1 <> Text2 Then

                ' insert row
                cell.EntireRow.Insert
            End If
        End If

        ' set second string for next time through loop
        Text2 = Text1
    Next
End Sub
```